# Lost connection EC2 and connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type which when started works well and the status check is ok, after a few minutes (4-5min) running, I can no longer connect to the server via ssh and the server does not respond to http requests, but the status check remains ok, I have already created other ec2 with other operating systems and the same problem happened, I tried to put it in another AZ and the problem remains, any idea what it might be?

Comment: Are you installing something on the server? do the cloudwatch metrics indicate high load?

Comment: no, just installed apache to make requests and show simple page. no have customers to cause overload

Comment: if I do the same scenario in other aws region, the problem are resolved